# How to use ListView.builder with groupBy in build method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list like this:

```
List<ProductModel> productList = [
    ProductModel(name: "Oranges", date: "2023-05-01"),    
    ProductModel(name: "Apples", date: "2023-05-01"),
    ProductModel(name: "Kiwis", date: "2023-03-01"),
];
```

I would like to group the items by date using groupBy and display it in Widget build as so:

```
2023-05-01:
Oranges
Apples

2023-03-01:
Kiwis
```

I have already done the grouping in a list and when printed my `groupByDate` list looks like so:

```
{2023-05-01: [Instance of 'ProductModel', Instance of 'ProductModel'], 2023-03-01: [Instance of 'ProductModel']}
```

Now, the question is how do I use `ListView.builder` to display the list items in build method:

```
class ProductListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ProductListPageState();
}

class _ProductListPageState extends State<ProductListPage> {
  late StreamController<int> _postsController;
  var groupByDate;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _postsController = new StreamController();
    getProducts();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getProducts() {
    Fetch.getProdcuts().then((value) => {
      _postsController.add(1);
      
      List<ProductModel> productList = [];

      for (var item in value!) {    
         final encode = json.encode(item.toJson());
         final product = ProductModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(encode));
         productList.add(product);
      }    
      groupByDate = groupBy(productList, (obj) => (obj! as ProductModel).date);

    });
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {            
      return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: groupByDate.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final key = groupByDate.keys.elementAt(index);
              final values = groupByDate.values.elementAt(index);
              return Column(
                children: [
                   Text("$key"),
                   Column(
                     children: [
                       //How do I show the list with values here??? 
                       entry.value.map((e) => Text(e.name)).toList(),
                   ])
              ])
            }
        )
      );
    }

class ProductModel extends Object {
  String? name;
  String? date;

  ProductModel({this.name, this.date});

  ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json["name"];
    date = json["date"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'name': name,
    'date': date,
  };
}
```

Comment: Have you tried https://pub.dev/packages/group_grid_view

Comment: before you've edited the code in the question, it was clearer what the problem is, because there in the comment you had mentioned the compiler errors that you had. so my answer is based on that.

Comment: Yes, I edited the code because I had a typo, which I saw after I posted the question. Still, your suggestion is worthwhile, I was actually considering how to define the  `groupByDate` variable just at the same time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is define your `groupByDate` variable as `Map`. Instead of just

```
var groupByDate;
```

change that to

```
var groupByDate = <String, List<ProductModel>>{};
```

so the compiler would know it's a map.

**Edit.** Upon question clarification, here's how you show the list of grouped values

```
 ListView.builder(
        itemCount: groupByDate.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final key = groupByDate.keys.elementAt(index);
          final values = groupByDate.values.elementAt(index);
          return Column(children: [
            Text("$key"),
            for (var item in values)
            Text("${item.name}"),
          ]);
        })
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Olga! The initial error was because I was using the wrong list in `ListView.builder` (a typo). I saw that once I posted the question. Now the code works even if I don't define the `groupByDate` variable  but your suggestion makes the code better. Now I am facing another issue -> How do I list the values in  `groupByDate` Map?

Comment: no problem, check the update. very similar to the second answer you've received

Comment: Thank you, Olga! I didn't know I could do for loop inside return! Now I know!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `groupByDate.entries` to get a list of entries in a `Map`, that way you will have access to both `key` & `value`:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: groupByDate.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final entry = groupByDate.entries.elementAt(index);
            return Column(children: [
              Text(entry.key ??
                  ''), 
              Column(
                children: entry.value.map((e) => Text(e.name ?? '')).toList(),
              )
            ]);
          }));
}
```